# Jenkins - Triggering build using URL always prompts for parameters

Tags: svn, jenkins, visualsvn-server

I have a Jenkins project that can build my web application from a specific version number in my VisualSVN repository.

I have done this by hardcoding the version number in the repository URL in the Source Code Management section of the Jenkins project.

[image]

I can trigger this build by going to a browser and entering a URL such as below, and this works great!

```
JENKINS_URL/job/ProjectName/build?token=TOKEN_NAME
```

I have now adapted the project so the version number is not hard coded but a parameter.

[image]

[image]

But when I go to build using a url like the following:

```
JENKINS_URL/job/ProjectName/build?token=TOKEN_NAME&VersionNumber=150
```

I get a prompt screen asking me to enter the parameter value:

[image]

When I enter the parameter in the text box the build project starts fine. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

According to the Launching a build with parameters section on the [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) page of the jenkins documentation you need to change your url to say `buildWithParameters` instead of just `build`.

So:

```
JENKINS_URL/job/ProjectName/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME&VersionNumber=150
```